# What is the difference between 'for...in' and 'for each...in' in javascript?

Tags: javascript, foreach, for-loop

I know in C# you use foreach like this: `foreach string str in array1 {console.writeline(str);}`
Is "for each ... in" used like that in JavaScript too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Afaik only Firefox supportes [`for each...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in). It is not part of any standard and most tools like [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) will throw errors if they encountered it.

The difference is that `for...in` loops over the **keys** of an object whereas `for each...in` loops over the **values**.

So the recommended way is to *not use* `for each` and do

```
for (var key in obj) {
    console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

instead.

**Update:** I cannot say how it relates to C#. But regarding arrays: **Never** use `for...in` to traverse arrays ([yellow box here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)):

> Although it may be tempting to use this as a way to iterate over an Array, this is a bad idea. The `for...in` statement iterates over user-defined properties in addition to the array elements, so if you modify the array's non-integer or non-positive properties (e.g. by adding a "foo" property to it or even by adding a method or property to `Array.prototype`), the `for...in` statement will return the name of your user-defined properties in addition to the numeric indexes.

Use a normal `for` loop instead:

```
for(var i = 0, l = arr.length; i<l; i++)
```

or more fancy:

```
for(var i = arr.length; i--;)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `for each in` in *standard* JavaScript. It may exist in specific implementations, if they want to extend the language.

`for..in` in JavaScript only relates to arrays by association, because it relates to objects, and arrays are objects. `for..in` does **not** loop through array entries, as `for each` does in C#. Nor does it loop through array indexes although people tend to think it does. (It loops through property names; array indexes are property names, but an array object can have other properties as well.) It's more like `for each` with the keys of a dictionary. I've discussed this fairly thoroughly [in this article](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html).

Answer (score 1):

"for each ... in" returns the values rather than the keys... See here:

http://www.dustindiaz.com/for-each-in/

Answer (score 0):

The `in` operator is used to enumerate the properties (the names, not the values) of a javascript `object` - and in javascript, all non-primitives are objects (inherit from Object).

You use it like this

```
var obj = {
    a: "aaa",
    b: "bbb"
};

for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        console.log("obj has a property " + key + ", with a value of " + obj[key]);
    }
}
```

Since `in` also enumerates properties inherited through the prototype chain, we must use `hasOwnProperty` to check if these are indeed the objects own properties, and not just inherited ones.

Note that the `in` operator should never be used to enumerate the items stored in arrays - for this you should use a regular `for/while` loop using the index.